# Simple: What makes this query inefficent?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

```
SELECT 
    t1.`id` , 
    t1.`some_key` ,  
    t1.`date` ,
    t2.`data`
FROM `table1` AS `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `table2` AS `t2` ON t2.`id` = t1.`some_key`
WHERE DATE( t1.`date` ) = DATE( NOW( ) )
```

I'm trying to search for all records in table1 added today.  I do not know the number of records.  I tried adding an INDEX to the date column however my EXPLAIN still shows MySQL searching through all n many rows in table1.

EDIT::: Explain as requested

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra 
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   
1   PRIMARY     t2  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   t1.some_key     1   
2   DERIVED     table2  ALL     indx    NULL    NULL    NULL    5   Using where
```

Comment: Is there an index on `date`?  Even if there were, it would be more efficient to not use the `date()` function on the table and use a `>`.  `WHERE t1.date > DATE(NOW())`

Comment: My 0.02: Given the fact you transform indexed data, there's no way to know the result beforehand. result: full scan

Comment: Index or no index it stil does a full scan.  How would you go about this?

Answer (score 6):

You're doing a transformation on t1.date; you lose the benefit of your index because now your query needs to look at every column.  t1.date may be indexed, but DATE( t1.date ) isn't.

Comment: I tried doing it as internval + 0 second and it still scans all rows

Comment: You've got it.  Rather than transforming your date column, do a search for t1.date >= DATE(NOW()) AND t1.date < DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)).  As long as t1.date is indexed, this will let you use your index.

Answer (score 1):

Try refactoring the query

```
SELECT 
    t1.`id` , 
    t1.`some_key` ,  
    t1.`date` ,
    t2.`data`
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM `table1`
        WHERE `date` >= (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
    ) AS `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `table2` AS `t2`
    ON t2.`id` = t1.`some_key`
;
```

The expression `(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)` is midnight today

```
mysql> select (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND);
+-----------------------------------+
| (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2012-06-15 00:00:00               |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is a second attempt

```
SELECT 
    t1.`id` , 
    t1.`some_key` ,  
    t1.`date` ,
    t2.`data`
FROM 
    (
        SELECT id,somekey FROM `table1`
        WHERE `date` >= (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
    ) AS t1
    INNER JOIN `table2` AS `t2` ON t1.`some_key` = t2.`id`;
;
```

Please make sure table1 has a (date,id,somekey) index

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX date_id_somekey_index (`date`,id,somekey);
```

The subquery is a pure range scan on an index, NO TABLE ACCESS !!!

I also changed the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.

To at least investigate the subquery run it alone:

```
SELECT id,somekey FROM `table1`
WHERE `date` >= (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND);
```

This subquery will only produced today's entries for t1

Comment: This will actually make it run SLOWER (even by microseconds) due to the additional overhead of making it a subquery.  This won't boost the performance of the query in question.  Plus returning everything (*) doesn't help ;)

Comment: Yes it still did a scan of all rows on the derived table 1

Comment: Please make the suggested index and run the EXPLAIN plan on my second query and post the output in your question.

Comment: Done thanks :).  There are 5 rows in table1 btw.  Only 4 have todays date

Comment: Please run my second query and let me know if it ran fast or not

Comment: That was your second query (the explain above)

Comment: That was the second attempt query.  11 microseconds however there are near no rows in the table.  I am worried due to the fact that it searches all 5 rows.  Imagine 100,000 rows

Comment: Of course, a full table scan would happen. Why? Your dataset is terribly small. The MySQL Query Optimizer is doing the right thing. As a rule of thimb, if the Query Optimizer sees that it has to read more than 5% of the the table using the index, it chooses not to use the index. In this case, 80% of the rows (4 out of 5) fulfills the subquery on table1. Try populating the table with 1000 rows and try my query again.